# What is the computational complexity of sin and cos for floating point inputs?

Tags: na.numerical-analysis

What is the computational complexity of the problem

INPUT: $\;\;\;$ integers $x$ and $y \:$ (both in binary)

OUTPUT:

rational approximations to $\: \sin\hspace{-0.03 in}\left(x\hspace{-0.04 in}\cdot \hspace{-0.04 in}2^{\hspace{.02 in}y}\hspace{-0.02 in}\right) \:$ and $\: \cos\hspace{-0.03 in}\left(x\hspace{-0.04 in}\cdot \hspace{-0.04 in}2^{\hspace{.02 in}y}\hspace{-0.02 in}\right)$

whose absolute errors are each less than $1/\hspace{-0.04 in}\left(2^{\hspace{.02 in}\operatorname{length}(x)}\hspace{-0.05 in}\right)$

?

One could just expand $\: x\hspace{-0.04 in}\cdot \hspace{-0.04 in}2^{\hspace{.02 in}y} \:$, $\:$ but that would use at least $\:\left|\hspace{.03 in}y\right|\:$ bits of *space*.

(I believe most work on the complexity of such functions

only considers their restrictions to compact intervals.)

Comment: sin and cos are (in the conventional representation) computable in uniform $\mathrm{TC}^0$, which implies that your problem is doable in the counting hierarchy (hence in polynomial space). It should be possible to estimate the relevant level of the hierarchy more precisely, but I do not see trigonometric functions mentioned in http://eccc.hpi-web.de/report/2013/177 , so it’s quite possible no one tried yet.

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that the problem is equivalent to computing an approximation of $x2^y\bmod2\pi$.

Comment: Which, on further thought, is equivalent to just computing an approximation of $2^y\bmod2\pi$ (with $\approx\log x$ bits of precision).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\def\tc{\mathrm{TC}^0}\DeclareMathOperator\len{len}$Since there were no other takers, let me expand the comments above.

The fundamental fact here is that approximations of basic arithmetic operations, and trigonometric and cyclometric functions like $\sin x$, $\cos x$, $\arctan x$, are computable in uniform $\tc$ (and therefore in logarithmic space) for **fixed-point** rational inputs. See e.g. [Reif](https://www.cs.duke.edu/%7Ereif/paper/logcircuit.pdf), [Reif and Tate](https://www.cs.duke.edu/%7Ereif/paper/tate/thresh.pdf), [Maciel and Thérien](http://dx.doi.org/10.1006/inco.1998.2783) for the basic arguments, however, the most crucial result for the uniform version is the proof that integer division and iterated multiplication are in uniform $\tc$ by [Hesse, Allender, and Barrington](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0022-0000(02)00025-9). This is optimal in that all such functions (except addition and subtraction) are $\tc$-complete.

(These results are typically stated for approximation of functions on a bounded domain, but they apply to arbitrary fixed-point inputs all the same, the point being that as long as there is only a linear number of bits before the binary point, we can reduce the input modulo $2\pi$ by just computing an approximation of $2\pi$ with a sufficent accuracy, followed by a division.)

This has several consequences.

**First**, $\sin(x2^y)$ and $\cos(x2^y)$ can also be approximated in uniform $\tc$ when $y$ is *negative*, by converting the input to fixed-point notation up to the desired accuracy. Thus, from now on I will only consider the case with $y\ge0$. We can as well also assume $x\ge0$, as this only affects the sign of sin.

**Second**, the problem is not really about trigonometric functions, as all the complexity is in reducing the input to a bounded domain. More precisely, we have:

> **Proposition 1:** The following search problems are equivalent up to uniform $\tc$ (and a fortiori log-space) bounded-query Turing reductions:
>
> 1. Given $x,y$, approximate $\sin(x2^y)$ and $\cos(x2^y)$ to $\len(x)$ bits of accuracy.
> 2. Given $x,y$, approximate $\sin(x2^y)$ to $\len(x)$ bits of accuracy.
> 3. Given $x,y$, approximate $x2^y\bmod 2\pi$ to $\len(x)$ bits of accuracy.
> 4. Given $y$ and unary $n$, approximate $2^y\bmod \pi$ to $n$ bits of accuracy.

Here, approximation of $z\bmod2\pi$ is defined so that when $z$ is very close to an integer multiple of $2\pi$, numbers close to $0$ and close to $2\pi$ are both considered valid outputs.

*Proof:* For $1\le2$, use the identity $\cos z=1-2\sin^2(z/2)$. For $1\le3$, $\sin$ and $\cos$ are $2\pi$-periodic, and computable on $[0,2\pi]$ in $\tc$. For $3\le1$, we can compute $z\bmod2\pi$ from $u=\cos z$ and $v=\sin z$ in $\tc$ using $\arctan(v/u)$ and a little fiddling with quadrants. For $3\le4$, compute $2^y\bmod2\pi$ to $2\len(x)+O(1)$ bits of accuracy, and use $x2^y\bmod2\pi=x(2^y\bmod2\pi)\bmod2\pi$, which holds as $x$ is an integer. QED

Curiously, the argument above gives a reduction of $\cos(x2^y)$ to $\sin(x2^y)$—or actually to $|\sin(x2^y)|$—and conversely we can reduce $|\sin(x2^y)|$ to $\cos(x2^y)$ using the identity $\sin z=\pm\sqrt{1-\cos^2z}$, but I don’t know how to reduce $\sin(x2^y)$ itself to $\cos(x2^y)$.

**Third**, exponentially scaled uniform $\tc$ circuits can be evaluated with $O(1)$ alternations of existential and universal nondeterminism, and counting. That is,

> **Proposition 2:** The problems from Proposition 1 are computable in the [counting hierarchy](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:C#ch) FCH, and therefore in polynomial space.

(Notice that the trivial algorithm that expands $x2^y$ in full followed by a computation of $\sin,\cos$ only gives an exponential-time upper bound, so this is an improvement.)

The level of CH the problem lands in corresponds to the depth of the uniform $\tc$ circuits, up to small differences depending on the exact definitions of the levels and the circuit model. The recent paper by [Allender, Balaji, and Datta](http://eccc.hpi-web.de/report/2013/177/) tries to optimize the level for some of the basic ingredients (division, iterated multiplication). They do not mention trigonometric functions, so this would need further work, however it is a safe guess that the argument should give something in the vicinity of the 3rd–5th level of CH.

Comment: In fact, it looks like the scaling argument shows that the problem can be solved in [DTISP](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:D#dtisp)(poly(length(x)+|y|),O(length(x)+length(y))). $\;$